# Show Content And Webform Same Page

Tags: webforms

I Am Making A Contact Page In Drupal 7 In Which I Have To Show Office Address And A Contact Form Made With Webform Show Together So Can Anyone Suggest Any Idea How To Show A Content And Webform In Same Page

Comment: Webform settings -> make available as a block -> place block on any page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webform, you can go to form settings, and in the advanced tab at the bottom, there is an option expose your form as a block.

Then go to structure > blocks and place the webform block on the page/region that you want.